# Systemd service leaves out command in script

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, boot, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to start a service named `pigpiod.service` via systemd. It invokes a script with three commands. The second one is left out. Why is this?

/etc/systemd/system/pigpiod.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts pigpiod
Before=touchscreen.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/sysop/pigpiod.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/home/sysop/pigpiod.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

touch /home/sysop/before_pigpiod
/usr/bin/pigpiod
touch /home/sysop/after_pigpiod
```

- When restarting the machine the two files get created in `/home/sysop/`, but `pigpiod` is not starting.
- When starting the service manually via `sudo systemctl start pigpiod` the same happens.
- When running `sudo /home/sysop/pigpiod.sh` manually `pigpiod` is actually starting!

This is the output of `sudo systemctl status pigpiod -l` right after boot:

```
● pigpiod.service - Starts pigpiod
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2017-09-16 20:02:03 UTC; 2min 29s ago
  Process: 440 ExecStart=/home/sysop/pigpiod.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 440 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 16 20:02:02 kivypie systemd[1]: Starting Starts pigpiod...
Sep 16 20:02:02 kivypie systemd[1]: Started Starts pigpiod.
```

Why is it, that systemd skips the execution of `/usr/bin/pigpiod`, but manually running the script as root does not?

My system: Raspberry Pi Model 3B, Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pigpiod` forks without the `-g` option. So use `Type = forking` or use `pigpiod -g`

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts pigpiod
Before=touchscreen.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/sysop/pigpiod.sh
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```